# Configure a server to execute software like Matlab, SPSS etc on Server from multiple clients simultanously

Tags: matlab, azure, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, spss

I have a big server in my department. We have around 60 students accessing it to run software like SPSS, R, Matlab etc to perform their work. At the moment server is configured in linux and clients are mostly MAC and Windows. The problem is that there are compatibility issues of SPSS, Matlab with linux and also the users are not familier with linux desktop which are making the process complicated. I searched and found that their is Remote desktop services server in windows to do similar jobs However Ideally I would like to configure a server in windows in such a way that users log in to the server using remote desktop from windows or mac and do their work and logout. Its simple client server configuration environment I am searching for in windows?

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but maybe an alternative: I've professionally used matlab on a linux server from windows clients on a previous job; We had 3 options:

1. [vnc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) into the server and do everything through vnc
2. ssh (eg: [putty](http://www.putty.org)) and only use commandline
3. Forward the screen to Windows; eg with [MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/)

The third option was pretty simple to use and offered windows-like user experience:

- open MobaXterm, connect to server (you can create favourites)
- specify username + password (it asks for it + option to 'remember')
- type "matlab" + enter
- gui of matlab opens, user experience is the same as he would have opened locally installed matlab (except for X-look-and-feel)

Matlab was just installed on the server locally, I don't know how they solved licensing issues (because basically everything would probably run just fine using one single license on that machine)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It is very close to what we are doing now i.e. (combination of 1 and 2). I will try the 3rd step. The problem is that Matlab runs fine when hosted on linux but SPSS is not functioning smoothly. Since we are hosting multiple applications I like to setup server which can allow multiple remote desktop so all the users can login simultaneously and run any application.